# output: export to generate a static build in nextjs14 is not loading css styles

Tags: next.js, build, static, tailwind-css, next.js13

I'm using tailwind in my project, everything works perfectly in yarn dev or even yarn start which would be the build files

but the out files, which would be the static files, do not load the css, everything comes without css.

Does anyone know what it is ? AGAIN: Everything works perfectly in dev mode and yarn start, but in static mode, which is located inside the /out folder, the css is not included.

Im using NEXTjs14

My global css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root {
  --foreground-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --background-start-rgb: 214, 219, 220;
  --background-end-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --foreground-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --background-start-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
    --background-end-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  }
}

body {
  color: rgb(var(--foreground-rgb));
  background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      transparent,
      rgb(var(--background-end-rgb))
    )
    rgb(var(--background-start-rgb));
}

@layer utilities {
  .text-balance {
    text-wrap: balance;
  }
}
```